# How to Ad Parameters to XML URL?

Tags: php, json, xml, parameters

URL is https://xmlfeed.game.eu/xmloddsfeed/v2/xml/feed.ashx?apikey=8712-d4953-ed11-9f37-003042d5&includeFraction=true&includeCent=true

I want to add a parameter delta="60"

Thanks

I tried

https://xmlfeed.game.eu/xmloddsfeed/v2/xml/feed.ashx?apikey=875e92-d453-ed11-9f37-003048dd5&Delta=60

Comment: Both of those links are redirecting to game.co.uk webpage. What is the output you are getting and what is the expected output?

Comment: I just stripped out some API Key and link its not for public viewing, the Delta=60 is a parameter the xml feed provided instead of the default built in of 20 minutes.  Delta=60 means xml pulls data the last 60 minutes instead of built in 20, its optional but have no idea how to add to xml URL. Thanks